# Using "take" instead of "need" in formal writing vs casual speech

Tags: formality

Is there any preference regarding the use of the following sentences in formal writing vs casual speech? I mean is it acceptable to use "take" in a formal writing in the meaning of need (or require)? Which forms of the following sentences are we more likely to hear in a casual conversation?

> 1.a Being successful in this work takes due attention.

> 1.b Being successful in this work needs due attention.

> 2.a The cooking process only takes ten minutes.

> 2.b The cooking process only needs ten minutes.

> 3.a Striking up good friendships with others takes getting to know yourself first.

> 3.b Striking up good friendships with others needs getting to know yourself first.

Comment: _Takes_ is much more usual when a period of time is mentioned (so 2a is more standard than 2b).

Comment: We wouldn't say due attention here really. My husband needs attention when he gets home from work. Being successful at this job requires paying proper attention. For example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are grammatically valid, an any o them might appear in either casual or formal English. Except perhaps (3B) which seems a little awkward, I might use 'requires" instead of "needs" there.  No rule violated by 3B, but "needs" is not usually used in quite that way.